# GWT Form upload without refresh or forward

Tags: java, gwt

I'm wondering if what should be done for GWT `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload`
to upload to server without refresh or forwarding.

I have implemented the Form upload from this [Java Doc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html), however it forwards the browser page to the target server URL.

How can I implement a form upload without forwarding?

**Update:**

```
    final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
    form.setAction("/upload");
    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART); 
    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

    VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
    form.setWidget(panel);
    final TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.setName("textBoxFormElement");
    panel.add(tb);

    // Create a FileUpload widget.
    FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
    upload.setName("uploadFormElement");
    panel.add(upload);      

    DOM.getElementById("form_panel").appendChild(panel.getElement());

    Button submit = new Button("Submit");
    panel.add(submit);

    DOM.sinkEvents(submit.getElement(), Event.ONCLICK);
    DOM.setEventListener(submit.getElement(), new EventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONCLICK) {
            form.submit();
            return;
        }
    }});
    form.addSubmitHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitHandler() {
      public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
        if (tb.getText().length() == 0) {
          Window.alert("The text box must not be empty");
          event.cancel();
        }
      }
    });
    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
      public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        Window.alert(event.getResults());
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: @Ümit I have updated the question with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you are making things more complex than they are.

I don't understand why, if you are using widgets, you are trying to manage the DOM by hand.

1.- Attach your form panel to the root panel using GWT way, otherwise you are going to break widget hierarchy.

```
 RootPanel.get("form_panel").add(panel);
```

2.- Try not to use sink-events by hand, and use methods already present in widgets:

```
 submit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      form.submit();
   }
 });
```

`FormPanel` sets its target to a hidden `<iframe>` so you will never be redirected to another page.

BTW, I'd rather use [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) library which simplifies so much uploading code in GWT, and adds a lot of additional features.

Comment: you mean this code: DOM.getElementById("form_panel").appendChild(panel.getElement());

I need to do this as form_panel is created by jQuery dynamically

Comment: `RootPanel.get("id_element")` also works with dynamically created elements

Answer (score 1):

I used before gwt-upload library.

You dont need to rediscover America.

Thanks for moxie group

[gwt-upload-project page](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/)